# Slab based calculation in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to calculate the slab based logic.

This is my table where the min_bucket and max_bucket range is mention and also the rate of it.

```
slabs   min_bucket  max_bucket  rate_per_month
----------------------------------------------
Slab 1        0      300000         20
Slab 2   300000      500000         17
Slab 3   500000     1000000         14
Slab 4  1000000                     13
```

We need to calculate as

- If there are 450k subs, the payout will be 300k*20 + 150k*17
- If the Total Count is 1000001, then its output should be as

```
min_bucket  max_bucket  rate_per_month  Count   rate_per_month  revenue
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
0            300000         20          300000      20          6000000
300000       500000         17          500000      17          8500000
500000      1000000         14          200001      14          2800014
```

Where count is calculated as 300000+500000+200001 = 1000001, and revenue is calculated as rate_per_month * Count as per the slab.

Can anyone help me write the SQL query for this, which will handle all the cases?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

You can build running totals of the slabs table and work with them:

```
with given as (select 1000001 as value)
, slabs as
(
  select
    slab,
    min_bucket,
    max_bucket,
    rate_per_month,
    sum(min_bucket) over (order by min_bucket) as sum_min_bucket,
    sum(coalesce(max_bucket, 2147483647)) over (order by min_bucket) as sum_max_bucket
  from mytable
)
select
  slabs.slab,
  slabs.min_bucket,
  slabs.max_bucket,
  slabs.rate_per_month,
  case when slabs.sum_max_bucket <= given.value
       then slabs.max_bucket
       else given.value - sum_min_bucket
  end as used,
  case when slabs.sum_max_bucket <= given.value
       then slabs.max_bucket
       else given.value - sum_min_bucket
  end * slabs.rate_per_month as revenue
from given
join slabs on slabs.sum_min_bucket < given.value
order by slabs.min_bucket;
```

I don't know your DBMS, but this is standard SQL and likely to work for you (either right away or with a little tweak).

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9c4f5f837b6167c7e4f2f7e571f4b26f